# django delete post noReverseMatch

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, django-urls

Trying to delete a post, but somehow getting a NoReverseMatch

views.py

```
@login_required
def task_detail(request, slug):
    '''
    Detailed view of all tasks on given project
    '''
    context = {}
    checklist   = get_object_or_404(Checklist, slug=slug)
    context.update({'checklist':checklist})
    form        = NotesForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.is_valid():
            print("\n\n for is valid")
            author = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user) 
            new_note = form.save(commit=False)
            new_note.user = author
            new_note.checklist = checklist
            new_note.save()

            return redirect('task_detail', slug=slug)

    context.update({
        'form': form,
        'title': checklist,
    })

    return render(request, 'projects/checklist.html', context)

@login_required
def delete_notes(request, note_id = None):
    del_note = Note.objects.get(id = note_id)
    del_note.delete()

    return redirect('teams')
```

My urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('projects/', teams, name='teams'),
    path('projects/project/<slug>/', projects, name='projects'),
    path('projects/tasks/<slug>/', project_detail, name='project_detail'),
    path('projects/checklist/<slug>/', task_detail, name='task_detail'),
    path('projects/checklist/delete_notes/', delete_notes, name='delete_notes'),
]
```

in the html I have just a href with the url to delete

```
<a class="dropdown-item text-danger" href="{% url 'delete_notes' notes.id %}">Delete</a>
```

Getting; Reverse for 'delete_notes' with arguments '(14,)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['projects/checklist/delete_notes/\Z']

Not really sure what is missing, thought the slug from checklist was already passed?

### Redirect Update

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('projects/', teams, name='teams'),
    path('projects/project/<slug>/', projects, name='projects'),
    path('projects/tasks/<slug>/', project_detail, name='project_detail'),
    path('projects/checklist/<slug>/', task_detail, name='task_detail'),
    path('projects/checklist/delete_notes/<int:note_id>/<slug:slug>/', delete_notes, name='delete_notes'),
```

```
@login_required
@require_http_methods(['post', 'delete'])
def delete_notes(request, note_id, slug):
    '''
    Delete given note
    '''
    del_note = Note.objects.filter(id=note_id).delete()
    return redirect('task_detail', slug=slug)
```

Updated with the slug

in html

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'delete_notes' notes.id title.slug %}">
     {% csrf_token %}
     <a class="dropdown-item">
        <button type="submit"class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
     </a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify a parameter where to put the `notes.id` parameter, for example:

```
path('projects/checklist/delete_notes/<int:note_id>/', delete_notes, name='delete_notes'),
```

Such view however should only be triggered with a POST or DELETE request, not with a GET request: a GET request should only be used to *retrieve* data, not to alter entities.

So you protect the view with:

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

@login_required
@require_http_methods(['POST', 'DELETE'])
def delete_notes(request, note_id):
    Note.objects.filter(id=note_id).delete()
    return redirect('teams')
```

and in the template you should work with a "mini-form":

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'delete_notes' notes.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

If you want to redirect to the `task_detail` of a given task, you can add an extra parameter:

```
path('projects/checklist/delete_notes/<int:note_id>/<slug:slug>/', delete_notes, name='delete_notes'),
```

and redirect with:

```
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

@login_required
@require_http_methods(['POST', 'DELETE'])
def delete_notes(request, note_id, slug):
    Note.objects.filter(id=note_id).delete()
    return redirect('task_detail', slug=slug)
```

then in the form you should pass the slug of the task:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'delete_notes' notes.id task.slug %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: That worked, thank you. However inn my redirect in views. How do i manage to redirect to the task_detail, passing a slug?

Comment: @MerrinX: then you should add an extra `<slug:slug>` parameter, and redirect to `return redirect('task_detail', slug=slug)`.

Comment: Could you give an example please

Comment: @MerrinX: see edit. The `task.slug` should of course be an expression that obtains the slug of a given task. If you use `task_detail` to render the template, it is thus `title.slug`.

Comment: The problem now with the redirect is that it throws inn the id projects/checklist/delete_notes/17/keep-whitin-project/ and there is no page there..

Comment: @MerrinX: did you update the `delete_notes` view to add a `slug` parameter?

Comment: updated the question, please see if you have time

Comment: @MerrinX: the `{% url 'delete_notes' notes.id slug %}` needs to contain a value for the slug to redirect to. So in this case `slug` needs to be an expression that resolves to the slug of the task. Furthermore you should write a miniform to make a POST request, otherwise you are violating the HTTP specs on *safe methods*: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.1.1

Comment: It does not redirect, it gives me the url, which is projects/checklist/delete_notes/<int:note_id>/<slug:slug>/'

for id, it passes the id of the post, and slug is correct, the title. but it should redirect to 
projects/checklist/<slug>/ where slug is the title

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241388/discussion-between-merrinx-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: @MerrinX: the `POST` and `DELETE` should be in uppercase in `@require_http_methods(['post', 'delete'])`.

Comment: I feel sick, it works.. i tried without the method and it is fine. that is why it was not redirecting. Thank you. If you could explain what you ment with miniform, i would appreciate it

Comment: @MerrinX: you still should use a `require_http_method(['POST', 'DELETE'])` this is because GET requests, by the HTTP standard should *not* modify the database. Indeed, GET requests are considered safe: for example search engines will make GET requests to retrieve a webpage. If you thus enable deleting a note with a GET request, you make it possible that accidently a web scraper removes data for example.